# Custom post type media upload error with custom user role

Tags: custom-post-types, uploads, media, user-roles

I have created a custom post type named `product` and assigned a new role `manager` for it. Everythign works fine, except the media uploader for `product`. I can even upload images without any error directly in the `add media` section. So, I started to test with default `author`, and still same error! Amazingly `author` can upload images successfully, when they are in a default `post`, not in `product`!

The error message says: **An Error occurred in the upload. Please Try again later.**

Below is the code for custom post type:

```
function cpt_product() {
    $slug = 'product';
    $labels = array( //all the custom labels );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => '5.1',
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'revisions' ),
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => $slug,
        'capabilities' => array(
            'edit_post' => 'edit_' . $slug,
            'read_post' => 'read_' . $slug,
            'delete_post' => 'delete_' . $slug,
            'edit_posts' => 'edit_' . $slug . 's',
            'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_' . $slug . 's',
            'publish_posts' => 'publish_' . $slug . 's',
            'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_' . $slug . 's',
            'delete_posts' => 'delete_' . $slug . 's',
            'delete_private_posts' => 'delete_private_' . $slug . 's',
            'delete_published_posts' => 'delete_published_' . $slug . 's',
            'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_' . $slug . 's',
            'edit_private_posts' => 'edit_private_' . $slug . 's',
            'edit_published_posts' => 'edit_published_' . $slug . 's'
        ),
        'map_meta_cap' => true
    );

    register_post_type( $slug, $args );     
}
```

Below is the code for custom role `manager`

```
function add_manager () {
$role_manager = 'manager' ;
$displayname_manager = 'Manager';
$capabilities_manager = array (
    'read' => true,
    'edit_product' => true,
    'read_product' => true,
    'delete_product' => false,
    'edit_products' => true,
    'edit_others_products' => true,
    'publish_products' => true,
    'read_private_products' => true,
    'delete_products' => false,
    'delete_private_products' => false,
    'delete_published_products' => false,
    'delete_others_products' => false,
    'edit_private_products' => true,
    'edit_published_products' => true,
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'upload_files' => true
    );


    create_custom_role ( $role_manager, $displayname_manager, $capabilities_manager );
}
add_action('admin_init', 'add_manager');


function create_custom_role ( $rolename, $roledisplayname, $capabilities ) {
    if ( get_role ( $rolename ) ) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        add_role ( $rolename, $roledisplayname, $capabilities );
    }
}
```

Now I am completely lost here, and can't find a solution! Can anyone please help me and tell me what I missed, or did wrong? :(

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange. I have got it working by setting `edit_others_posts` and `edit_private_posts` to `true`!